# Google Cloud Platform Logger

Tags: google-smart-home

I have repeated warnings about occurred errors, but I can find any data about the error reasons and why they occur and how I can fix them.

The codes are:
`DEADLINE_EXCEEDED`, `BACKEND_FAILURE`, `OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE`

About some of them like `BACKEND_FAILURE` in `SMART_HOME_EXECUTE` I find that I return you that the device is offline (something like this `[{"ids":["device id"],"status":"OFFLINE"}]`), why this occurred?

For those `BACKEND_FAILURE` connected with the `SMART_HOME_QUERY` you tell me sometimes that I return you empty object, but in the other times nothing, and like I see in the logs, those request didn't come to me.

Where I can find information about reasons those error to occurred and how to fix them? I think this is a network issue, but how to prevent those error log?

Comment: Format the status codes & code snipper accrodingly

Answer (score 0):

- `OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE` should indicate an issues with account linking resulting in an authorization error when calling the fulfillment.
- `BACKEND_FAILURE` should indicate an other error returned by the fulfillment.

You should be able to introspect your fulfillment/authorization and token endpoint logs in your application server to diagnose those.

See also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158468798.